# Filling rows of a repeating table on opening the form

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

In my Infopath form I use a repeating table. On opening this form on sharepoint I would like to have some rows of the repeating table filled out using information from an other list. I use content types.

What i am working on is a Timesheet system where the user can register how many hours a week he worked on different projects.
I would like that by creation of a timesheet some predefined projects will be already inserted, meaning that the repeating table will have for example 5 rows already with 5 favourite or most used projects selected based on a separate PetProject list.

When I looked at the workflow in the list where the timesheet is being created I couldn’t find the column projectname in the dropdown so I cant give it a value. When I went to look in the Form settings of TimeSheets I saw that projectname cant be selected/edited, its in plain black whereas the other columns are blue and clickable. I thought its probably because the value of projectname is merged from the different rows in the repeating table.

Is there any way I can work around this problem and assign a value to projectname by creation of the timesheet?

Thank you so much!

Comment: If you narrow the scope of your question, I may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will need to write some code to query the data that you are after and add the data to new rows in the repeating table.

There is a loading event that you can hook into to then query a secondary data source and then
add the row to the repeating table.

Will this run with in infopath as a thick client or will it run as a browser based form using infopath form service?